# ping doesn't run after a windows server update

Tags: networking, ping, windows-server-2003

I break my head with this new problem ...
At beginning of April, my windows server sbs 2003 was updated (8 updates) automatically by Microsoft.

The OS restarted after these updates during the night.

Since this time my server doesn't "see" the gateway and cannot access to internet or cannot ping any other machines on the same switch ("REQUEST TIMED OUT").

I restarted it in safe mode, executed an anti-malwares tool, restarted in normal mode but nothing changed.

ipconfig/all didn't change. I disabled the firewall and the antivirus tool but nothing changed.

Nothing of special in the events log.
Note that I can ping from the other machines and access to internet.

But what is strange, for me, is, when I restart it in safe mode with networking, my server can ping any machines, can access to the gateway and therefore to internet. My first conclusions are:
- the switch is good (I tried to move the cable);
- the cable is good (I tried with another cable);
- the NIC is good because that's work in safe mode with networking.

Any ideas I could do, I could test again ?
Thank you by advance.

**Note:**
ping loopback /localhost 127.0.0.1 OK
ping myipmachine OK
ping myipgateway KO
restart gateway: not better

Comment: Tried rolling back the updates and testing them all individually?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Is it "last known good configuration" in the F8 menu ? If yes, I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: Yes: control panel add/remove programs, check show updates

Comment: Do you happen to have Routing and Remote Access enabled?

Comment: Already enabled

Comment: I rolled back the updates but nothing changed. I feel my OS is broken ...

Comment: Disable the Routing and Remote Access service; reboot and see if you can ping

Comment: I did it but cannot ping

Comment: I also tried to reset the tcp stack (netsh int p reset) and the winsock socket (netsh winsock reset)